Which analysis is suitable for comparing cross-correlation coefficients between experimental phases in a repeated measures design?
I have a repeated measures experimental design, with a within-subjects factor phase and a between-subjects factor order of phases. I will compare pairs of time series data (for pairs of participants) and want to check if cross-correlations differ based on the experimental phase and order of phases. I would like to know if it makes sense to plan ANOVA, or rather GLMM or LMM, or if it is necessary to first see the distribution of cross-correlation coefficients, apply transformations on the data and only then get an answer? I would appreciate a recommendation for a good literature on the topic.
